# Dataframe replace all True and False values wirth 1 and 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace all True and False values in my dataframe

```
  A       B      C      D
  12.23   False  43.34  True
  78.56   True   67.78  False
```

Convert to

```
      A       B      C      D
      12.23   0      43.34  1
      78.56   1      67.78  0
```

I tried with following, but it didn't made that change (didn't do any change)

```
dataset = dataset.replace(True,1)
dataset = dataset.replace(False,0)
```

Appreciate your insights.

Comment: `df.astype(int)` ?

Comment: that'd have a side effect on all other columns, probably not wanted

Comment: @RafaelC agreed :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `dict`

```
>>> df.replace({True:1, False:0})
```

```
    A       B   C       D
0   12.23   0   43.34   1
1   78.56   1   67.78   0
```

From [`docs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), argument `to_replace` accepts as input

> str, regex, list, dict, Series, int, float, or None

For any other (hashable) data types, use their values as keys in a dictionary.